# Private windows with require("sdk/window/utils").windows()

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I use in package.json: `"permissions": {"private-browsing": true}`

According to the description, it is enough to function `windows()` returns the private windows: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#Private_windows

However, they are still ignored.

What to do to `require("sdk/window/utils").windows();` returns the private windows?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a documentation bug (in both, the actual docs and the code comment in the implementation), but the implementation does not actually care about the `permissions`, just about an [undocumented option](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/c8288d0c7a15/addon-sdk/source/lib/sdk/window/utils.js#l284):

```
/**
 * Returns an array of all currently opened windows.
 * Note that these windows may still be loading.
 */
function windows(type, options) {
  options = options || {};
  let list = [];
  let winEnum = WM.getEnumerator(type);
  while (winEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
    let window = winEnum.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
    // Only add non-private windows when pb permission isn't set,
    // unless an option forces the addition of them.
    if (!window.closed && (options.includePrivate || !isWindowPrivate(window))) {
      list.push(window);
    }
  }
  return list;
}
exports.windows = windows;
```

So it turns out you need to call the function like this:

```
require("sdk/window/utils").windows(null, {includePrivate: true});
```

It would be great if you [filed a bug](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).